How to create Role Assignment with ARM C# SDK?
Namely, how to create role assignment that can be used for different principals (but for the same scope/role)?
All examples that I found (for example this answer) use role definition ID for a role assignment name which causes clashes if I want to create another assignment for the same scope and role but for a different principal.
The examples of ARM templates used for this, clearly have this separation:
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/providers/roleAssignments",
    "apiVersion": "2018-09-01-preview",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('StorageAccountName'), '/default/',parameters('ContainerName'), '/Microsoft.Authorization/', parameters('roleNameGuid'))]",
    "properties": {
      "roleDefinitionId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe')]",
      "principalId": "[parameters('principalId2')]"
    }      
}

Here name and principalId are clearly different and you can just use a different name for the different principal.
However in C# SDK, the role definition is passed as a roleAssignmentName:
var roleAssignmentResource = armClient.GetRoleAssignmentResource(
        RoleAssignmentResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(
            scope: $"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId.ToString()}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}",
            roleAssignmentName: "acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7")); // this is the ID for the Reader role

Why does C# SDK combine them? How do I decouple them to be able to create multiple assignments for different principals?

Could you confirm whether your requirement is to assign role to multiple service principals under same scope at once via c#?

@Sridevi yeah, that is correct.

@Sridevi I think I need to clarify; I don't want to create both assignments "at once" as in the "in the same call". Assignment is a procedure that might happen from time to time, and it should not depend on other assignments, even if they are for the same scope/role. So two assignments for different principals might need to coexist at some point.

You can create independent role assignments for different principals over time by generating unique roleAssignmentName values. This ensures that each assignment can coexist without dependency on others, even if they share the same scope and role.

Note that, role assignment name needs to be unique within a scope. If you use roleAssignmentName as role definition Id, it will create a clash when you are assigning role to multiple service principals under same scope.
Alternatively, you can generate unique roleAssignmentName values by using Guid.NewGuid().ToString() to avoid conflicts.
In my case, I used below modified code to create role assignments for different principals under same scope:
using Azure;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Authorization;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Authorization.Models;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);

        string subscriptionId = "subId";
        string resourceGroupName = "rgname";
        string scope = $"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}";

        // Define the role definition (Reader role in this case)
        string roleDefinitionId = "/subscriptions/subId/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7";

        string[] principalIds = new string[]
        {
            "userId01",
            "userId02"
        };

        foreach (var principalId in principalIds)
        {
            // Generate a GUID for the role assignment ID (it should be GUID based, not based on principalId)
            string roleAssignmentName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();  // Use GUID directly as role assignment ID

            ResourceIdentifier roleAssignmentResourceId = RoleAssignmentResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(scope, roleAssignmentName);

            RoleAssignmentResource roleAssignment = client.GetRoleAssignmentResource(roleAssignmentResourceId);

            RoleAssignmentCreateOrUpdateContent content = new RoleAssignmentCreateOrUpdateContent(
                new ResourceIdentifier(roleDefinitionId), Guid.Parse(principalId))
            {
                PrincipalType = RoleManagementPrincipalType.User  // Set to ServicePrincipal if assigning to a service principal
            };

            // Create or update the role assignment
            ArmOperation<RoleAssignmentResource> lro = await roleAssignment.UpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, content);
            RoleAssignmentResource result = lro.Value;
            RoleAssignmentData resourceData = result.Data;

            // Output the result
            Console.WriteLine("Role assignment created:");
            Console.WriteLine($"  Principal ID: {principalId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"  Role Definition ID: {roleDefinitionId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"  Assignment ID: {resourceData.Id}");
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 50));  // Separator line
        }
    }
}

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where role assigned successfully to users under same scope:

